# How to fix list list index out of range

Tags: python

I am having problems with this line. I am not really sure why it gives me list index out of range. I've tried couple of solutions so far none of them worked.

```py
def endGame(points):
    scoreboard = []
    with open("scoreboard.csv", "a") as scoreboardFile:
        scoreboardWriter = csv.writer(scoreboardFile)
        scoreboardWriter.writerow(name, points)
    scoreboardFile = open("scoreboard.csv", "rt")
    scoreboardReader = csv.reader(scoreboardFile)
    for i in scoreboardReader:
        scoreboard.append([i[0], int(i[1])])
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Nea\NEA-PROJECT.py",
> line 127, in <module>
>     endGame(points)   File "E:\Nea\NEA-PROJECT.py", line 25, in endGame
>     scoreboard.append([i[0], int(i[1])]) IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

This is supposed to write the name of the user and the score they achieved. The thing that confuses me is that it works the name and the score is saved on the file, but it gives me index list out of range.

Comment: submit the error traceback please

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot about it.

Comment: try appending the whole row at once:
        scoreboard.append(i)

Comment: What do you mean by appending the whole row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append the whole row at once in the for loop. Otherwise the line you had `[i[0], int(i[1])]` will fail when it finds a row in the `scoreboard.csv` that is empty (or has only 1 character), and then it tries to index into that.

Also you need to pass an iterable (like a list) to the `writerow` method, since as you can see from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) it only takes one argument.

```
def endGame(points):
    scoreboard = []
    with open("scoreboard.csv", "a") as scoreboardFile:
        scoreboardWriter = csv.writer(scoreboardFile)
        scoreboardWriter.writerow([name, points])  # CHANGED
    scoreboardFile = open("scoreboard.csv", "rt")
    scoreboardReader = csv.reader(scoreboardFile)
    for i in scoreboardReader:
        scoreboard.append(i)  # CHANGED
```

Comment: I tried that but then it gives me another error because of scoreboardWriter.writerow(name, points)

Comment: @LlambriThanasi What kind of error this code gives?

Comment: writerow needs an iterable, change ```(name, points)``` to ```([name, points])```

Comment: @LlambriThanasi That line should be `scoreboardWriter.writerow([name, points])`

Comment: Thanks it fixed my problem. Sadly I've made more errors. Ill try to work on it by my own if i need help ill post again. Thank u Again.

Comment: @LlambriThanasi Glad I could help :) Feel free to also [mark my answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)

Comment: @ruohola Thank you but if i append the whole row it gives me error on the next line but if I use (row) instead it works for some reason.

Comment: @LlambriThanasi Impossible to say what's the issue without seeing your code. Should probably read some tutorials or possibly post an other question about that.

Comment: @ruohola I edit the other part of the code in this post. You can check it and tell me if you need anything extra.

Comment: @LlambriThanasi `for i in scoreboardReader:
        scoreboard.append(row)` Should at least be `for row in ...`

Comment: @ruohola Actually I made some changes and your way was the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
import csv
scoreboard = []
with open("scoreboard.csv", "w", newline='') as scoreboardFile:
    scoreboardWriter = csv.writer(scoreboardFile)
    scoreboardWriter.writerow(('bugbeeb', 20))
with open("scoreboard.csv", "r") as  scoreboardFile:
    scoreboardReader = csv.reader(scoreboardFile)
    for row in scoreboardReader:
        scoreboard.append(row)
```

this should work for you

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.